# Express Nested routes in param?

Tags: regex, express

i have nested categories like: `/cars/trucks/ford/f350`
i need to all path to category will be in param (path).
Then i check path and get nested category (f350)

How can i make it ?

Now i use regex:

```js
app.route('/:slug([\\w/]+)');
```

but it works little bit wrong, because path `/cars////trucks////ford//f350` pass

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
'/:slug(\\w+(?:/\\w+)*)'
```

The regex matches

- `\\w+` - one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `(?:/\\w+)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `\\w+` - one or more letters, digits or underscores